# Feature-Based Image Morphing with C++/Qt

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, qt

I'm trying to implement Feature-Based Image Morphing algorithm which is described for example [here](http://davis.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/morph/2d.htm). I'm not sure if I correctly understand it, but I'll try explain my thoughts. Maybe someone of you can guide me where I missed something.
I used Qt/C++, but if you prefer other technologie and have nice examples, it can be also nice information for me. Let's start.

Pseudo code for this algorithm looks like below:

```
For each pixel X in the destination 
        DSUM=0 
        weightsum = 0 
        For each line PiQi 
             calculate u, v based on PiQi 
             calculate X’i based on u, v and P’iQ’i 
             calculate displacement Di=X’i-Xi for this line 
             dist= shortest distance from X to PiQi 
             weight = (lengthP / (a + dist))b 
             DSUM  += Di * weight 
             weightsum += weigth 
        X’ = X + DSUM / weightsum 
        destinationImage(X) = sourceImage(X’)
```

If I correctly understand it, the weightsum is needed for multiple line algorithm. If I have only one feature which I want to use to mesh image, pseudocode can look like this:

```
For each pixel X in the destination 
     calculate u, v based on PiQi 
     calculate X’i based on u, v and P’iQ’i
     destinationImage(X) = sourceImage(X’)
```

Let's start from begin. For each pixel X, so if my image is 512x512, I need two for loops to iterate through all pixels of image. So I make something like this for every pixel X

```
for(int h = 0; h < imgHeight; h++)
 {
     for(int w = 0; w < imgWidth; w++)
     {
         QPoint X(h,w);
         [..]
     }
}
```

Let's try to calculate u.

```
float u = dotProduct((X-P),(Q-P))/(lenght*lenght);
```

where dotProduct is function like below

```
float MainWindow::dotProduct(const QPoint & p, const QPoint &q)
{
    return p.x()*q.x()+p.y()*q.y();
}
```

and

```
float lenght = distance(Q,P);
float MainWindow::distance(QPoint p, QPoint q)
{
    int dx = p.x() - q.x();
    int dy = p.y() - q.y();
    float dist = sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy );
    return dist;
}
```

After that I calculate v

```
float v = dotProduct((X-P),perp(Q-P))/lenght;
```

where perp is function like below

```
QPoint MainWindow::perp(const QPoint &p)
{
    return QPoint(p.x()*(-1),p.y());
}
```

So if I have u and v, I can calculate new position of pixel. I'm doing it like below:

```
QPoint x = PPrim + u*(QPrim-PPrim)+ (v*perp(QPrim-PPrim))/distance(QPrim,PPrim);
```

The problem I have is almost all pixels after that has values that are outside image, so almost all pixels are more than 512 or less than 0 in X or Y value of pixel. Because of that, I see only narrow of pixels in the middle and the rest values are missing.

For example for input data like this:

```
image 512,512
X(0,0)
Q(244,257) P(268,255) 
Q'(246,254) P'(266,258) 
u = 10.2103 
v = -288.251 
x = QPoint(-221,274)
```

which is I think wrong. Do you have any idea where I'm doing it bad? Did I miss something?

Comment: I believe your `perp()` function is wrong and had to return `QPoint(-p.y(), p.x())` instead. (It must be x' = -y, y' = x, but you didn't "swap" x and y.)

Comment: Thank you Sheff! I can't belive I really missed that! Thanks a lot. I think if image should be rotated? It look like I missed some pixels in the corners.